# How to calculate the first date and last date in a Period in Oracle SQL as per Gregorian Calendar

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to build a query to get the first date and last date of a period in Oracle SQL database as per the [4-4-5 calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar) to achieve something like below:

[image]

Can anyone help me in the same? I tried with the below queries but not able to reach to the point:

```
alter session set NLS_TERRITORY = 'THE NETHERLANDS';
alter session set NLS_CALENDAR='GREGORIAN';
SELECT add_months(trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1), 1) -1 FROM dual;
```

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the same. Kindly check !!

Comment: Can you edit the question and give examples *in the question* of what you are looking for?

Comment: Just saying "4-4-5 calendar" doesn't seem sufficient. It seems you need to provide more detail - for example, the first day of the first month is provided as an input. Alternatively, you need to state what the fiscal year is (January to December? July to next June? etc.), the definition of "week" (Monday to Sunday? Sunday to Saturday? etc.) and exactly when a fiscal year begins and/or ends (First Monday of a fiscal year is considered the first day of the fiscal year? What other convention is used?)

Comment: The key point is the start of the first period. Why is it 2.1.2017? Is 1.1.2017 skipped because it is Sunday? If you describes the rules for the start of the 1st period the task is solved; al other is simple arithmetic...

Answer (score 3):

The initial date of the first period is either provided externally (I did so, in a WITH clause; more likely it will be a bind variable, or an in parameter to a procedure), or it can be calculated based on rules, in a separate code block.

With the initial date given or calculated, the rest can be done, for example, as shown below.

```
with
  inputs ( input_date ) as (
    select date '2017-01-02' from dual
  )
select level as period_number,
       input_date + 28 * (level - 1) + 7 * trunc((level-1)/3) as period_start,
       input_date + 28 *  level - 1  + 7 * trunc( level   /3) as period_end,
       case mod(level, 3) when 0 then 35 else 28 end          as days_in_period
from   inputs
connect by level <= 12
;



PERIOD_NUMBER PERIOD_START PERIOD_END   DAYS_IN_PERIOD
------------- ------------ ------------ --------------
            1 2-1-2017     29-1-2017                28
            2 30-1-2017    26-2-2017                28
            3 27-2-2017    2-4-2017                 35
            4 3-4-2017     30-4-2017                28
            5 1-5-2017     28-5-2017                28
            6 29-5-2017    2-7-2017                 35
            7 3-7-2017     30-7-2017                28
            8 31-7-2017    27-8-2017                28
            9 28-8-2017    1-10-2017                35
           10 2-10-2017    29-10-2017               28
           11 30-10-2017   26-11-2017               28
           12 27-11-2017   31-12-2017               35
```